# ggplot: filling color based on condition

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to plot two categorical variables (group, condition) and one numeric variable (value). In addition, I want to base the filling color on the significance of the values (significant bars should be grey, the rest white). With the following code, however, only some significant bars are colored in grey.

```
plot <-  ggplot(dat, aes(group, value))+ 
  geom_col(aes(fill = condition), position = position_dodge(0.8), width = .7, color= "black") + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = ifelse(dat$significance > .05, "white", "grey")) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(group = condition,  ymin = ci_lower, ymax= ci_upper), position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  coord_flip(ylim =c(-.2,1)) 
plot
```

here is my data:

```
dat <-  structure(list(group = c("friends", "parent", "esm", "friends", "parent", "esm"), 
                       value = c(0.25, 0.44, 0.33, 0.47, 0.25, 0.32), 
                       significance = c(0.08, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0), 
                       condition = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2"), 
                       trait = c("E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"), 
                       ci_lower = c(0.52, 0.74, 0.53, 0.67, 0.44, 0.49), 
                       ci_upper = c(-0.03, 0.14, 0.14, 0.27, 0.06, 0.15)),
                  row.names = c(1L,2L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an inline `mutate` to create a column to specify the color group based on significance. The key here is to use the `group` aesthetic so the bars can still be dodged and positioned correctly based on the `condition` variable.

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(sig = significance < .05) %>%
  ggplot(aes(group, value, group = condition)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(fill = sig),
    position = position_dodge(0.8),
    color = "black",
    width = .7
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "grey")) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper),
                 position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(-.2, 1))
```

Gives this plot:

[image]

However, I think you need another aesthetic to distinguish `condition` in addition to significance. Color is one option, but this is a nice place to use `ggpattern` which will be more obvious than the outline color and keep the B&W look.

Here's an example:

```r
library(ggpattern)

dat %>%
  mutate(sig = significance > .05) %>%
  ggplot(aes(group, value, group = condition)) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(fill = sig, pattern_angle = condition),
    position = position_dodge(0.8),
    pattern_fill = "black",
    pattern_spacing = 0.025,
    pattern = "stripe",
    width = .7,
    color = "black"
  ) +
  scale_pattern_angle_discrete(range = c(45, 135)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "white")) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper),
                 position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(-.2, 1))
```

Which gives this plot:

[image: with ggpattern]

Finally, it's worth noting that the color of a bar is not usually used to denote significance of a statistical metric; a much more common convention would be to use asterisk to indicate relevant p value thresholds (e.g. ** p < 0.01) or letters to indicate membership in a grouped analysis such as an ANOVA. These can be easily implemented using the `ggpubr` package. That would leave fill color free to indicate the grouping by `condition`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it worked well!  Regarding your additional suggestions: I am aware that one typically does not use color for significance but in the final plot, I will combine twenty of these plots plus additional twenty other plots (for which I will use the pattern btw). For that reason, I wanted to use the grey color to make significance easier visible at first sight (the condition is not that important).

Answer (score 2):

It can also be useful:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(dat, aes(group, value))+ 
  geom_col(aes(fill = interaction(condition,significance > .05)), 
           position = position_dodge(0.8), width = .7, color= "black") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey","grey","white"),
                    breaks = c('S2.FALSE','S1.TRUE'),
                    labels=c('S2','S1')) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(group = condition,  ymin = ci_lower, ymax= ci_upper), position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  coord_flip(ylim =c(-.2,1))+
  labs(fill='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! With your suggested code, however, the confidence interval seems to switch between the conditions. In this example, it only happened in the friend group (cf. also the plot by Dan Adams). In total, I have twenty plots of these and in some of them it appears that the majority of confidence interval switches between conditions with your code.